# Putting citation in supercript within Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer, citations

I try do to cite some authors into my beamer. The citation takes place within a frametitle. It works perfectly fine until I want to superscript them. I try with package `[super]{cite}` and it doesn't work. I get some compilation problems:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@todo ...ust \edef \inserttocsectionnumber
                                              {\the \beamer@tempcount }\
```

To compile my work, i used the following bash:

```
pdflatex example
bibtex example
pdflatex example
pdflatex example
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by using the package natbib  and correctly use it especially by defining the bibliographystyle into the preamble and to define a blank function newblock in order to compile nicely.

The preamble should look like:

```
\documentclass[pdf,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[sort&compress,comma,super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % Or your specific bibliographystyle

\def\newblock{} % To avoid a compilation error about a function \newblock undefined

\begin{document}
 ...
```

Don't forget the `\citep{...}` and it should work fine.